# What important difference exists between Monitor.TryEnter(object) And Monitor.TryEnter(object, ref bool)?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, synchronization, monitor

It seems that these code snippets ought to behave identically:

### 1: Monitor.TryEnter(object)

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject))
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

### 2: Monitor.TryEnter(object, ref bool) - introduced in .NET 4.0

```
bool lockAcquired;
try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, ref lockAcquired);
    if (lockAcquired)
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
finally
{
    if (lockAcquired)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

I see from the MSDN documentation on [the overload taking a `ref bool` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679.aspx):

> If the lock was not taken because an
>   exception was thrown, the variable
>   specified for the *lockTaken* parameter
>   is **false** after this method ends. This
>   allows the program to determine, in
>   all cases, whether it is necessary to
>   release the lock.

But the documentation *also* states that the overload taking only the `object` parameter throws no exceptions other than `ArgumentNullException`. So it seems like if an exception were thrown in code snippet **1** above, it could only be because `lockObject` is `null`, in which case no lock was taken (and `TryEnter` would've returned `false`) anyway, so the `Monitor.Exit` call would not be needed.

Clearly they would not have introduced this overload for no reason. So what scenario is the `Monitor.TryEnter(object, ref bool)` method intended to address?

Comment: Wow, that took a while. This method is only present in .NET 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Monitor.TryEnter could succeed and then an asynchroneous exception like ThreadAbortException or OutOfMemoryException (that can happen without visible allocations) is triggered. Then the lock would be taken but never released.

See: [Locks and exceptions do not mix](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't this be true of either overload, though? That is, how would this scenario be prevented by the second overload?

Comment: Ohhh I see (visited the link)... so in other words an exception could be thrown after the `TryEnter` but before entering the `try`/`finally` block. Got it.

Comment: Too bad there's no "nice" way to apply similar logic to a "Using"-style block.  It's possible to kludge a constructor to 'sneak out' a reference to a partially-constructed object before it does anything that will need to be undone, and only invoke the constructor from a factory method which can use the smuggled reference to dispose the partially-constructed object, but it would be nice if there were a better way to do that.  Maybe change the framework so that if construction fails on an object which implements iDisposeOnConstructorException, the framework would call iDOCE.dispose on it?

Comment: The current JIT contains a hack that makes the 'sneak out' scenario impossible. You can also reimplement the using-block yourself: C c = null; try { c = new C(); } finally { if (c!= null) c.Dispose(); }

Comment: @usr: I don't think the "sneak-out" is impossible; if the constructor of the deepest base class that holds any `IDisposable` fields takes a `ref` parameter of type `IDisposable`, and copies `this` to that parameter, and all derived-class constructors contain a similar parameter and pass it to their parent, then even if an exception occurs sometime between the assignment of that parameter and the time the constructor exits, the object under construction will be available to the calling code.  It's a kludge, but it's the only safe way I know to ensure that things get cleaned up.

Comment: @usr: The try/finally would be `C myThing; try {CreateThing(ref myThing); } finally {if (myThing!= null) myThing.Dispose);}`.  The contract for `CreateThing` would specify that if it exits via exception, the caller must not do anything with `myThing` except `Dispose` it.

Comment: @supercat You're right. My comment from 2.5 years ago does not make much sense as it does not apply to what you said.

Comment: @usr: I just saw your comment and was curious whether the JIT had changed in some way that would interfere with what I was doing.  What sort of JIT hack were you talking about?

Comment: @supercat The JIT hack prevents an asynchronous exception from occurring with the pre-C# 4.0 lock statement: http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2005/04/12/jitlockhack (search for "hack").

Comment: @usr: Ah.  I think of the scenario targeted by the hack as the "leak"-out scenario.  I had thought your use of the term "sneak" was referring to my use of that term in the comment before yours.  The pattern of having a method that acquires a resource ensure that it will be available for cleanup in a `finally` block is IMHO one that should be used routinely; adding it to the one specific case of `Monitor.TryEnter` doesn't seem as good as making it available for resources in general.