# Is Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, timeout) overload unsafe? (.net)

Tags: c#

I was suggested during a code review to do

```
bool acquiredLock = false;
try {
    Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, 500, ref acquiredLock);
    if (acquiredLock) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
        // fallback strategy
   }
}
finally
{
    if (acquiredLock)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    }
}
```

instead of the simpler

```
if (Monitor.TryEnter(lockObject, 500)) {
      try {
          // do something...
      } 
      finally {
          Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
      }
} else {
     // fallback strategy
}
```

What difference does it make? How can the first code *not* exhibit a bug where the second would exhibit a bug?

Comment: Because you never exit the lock?

Comment: @SLaks Sorry, that was due to a mistake in the question. That's not the actual question. I'll fix the question.

Comment: You'll have to throw a Thread.Abort() in the mix and reason if your code still works properly.  Backgrounder [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14831590/17034), x64 jitter required to mess it up.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674650/what-important-difference-exists-between-monitor-tryenterobject-and-monitor-tr

Comment: Yes, that looks like a duplicate to me, even though all the function signatures are different!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming in your second snippet you'd *actually* call `Monitor.Exit`, the difference is explained in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd289679(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This overload always sets the value of the variable that is passed to the `ref` parameter `lockTaken`, even if the method throws an exception, so the value of the variable is a reliable way to test whether the lock has to be released.

In other words, with your second snippet, it might be feasible for an asynchronous exception to be thrown (e.g. the thread being aborted) after the lock has been acquired, but before the method has returned. Even with a `finally` block, you couldn't then easily tell whether or not you'd need to release the lock. Using the `ref` parameter, the "monitor acquired" and "`ref` parameter set to `true`" actions are atomic - it's impossible for the variable to have the wrong value when the method exits, however it exits.

As of C# 4, when targeting a platform supporting this overload, this is the code that the C# compiler generates too.

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet is exiting the monitor when the second is not.  You want to release the monitor when you're done with the critical block.

Comment: Sorry, that was due to a mistake in the question. That's not the actual question. I'll fix the question.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the entirely valid point about exiting that other posters have made... The [documentation for the TryEnter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270976(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it can throw one of three exceptions, so technically, yes it could bomb your application under specific circumstances.

Comment: Those documented exceptions are all argument validation exceptions. It seems highly unlikely you would get any of them after acquiring the lock.

Comment: Indeed. However: The statement Monitor.TryEnter is not enclosed in something that would catch those validation exceptions, at least not in the code snippet presented. It's possible that it could bomb at runtime.

Comment: What I mean is if you get any of those exceptions, obviously you haven't got the lock. You don't even need the ref lockTaken parameter to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Even tough the method is named `TryEnter`, it actually throws exceptions, and you need to handle them properly. If it throws an exception and you don't handle it and release monitor, you can have a deadlock situation.

This maybe a bit too precautious, because if you look at exception that it actually throws, it will *most probably* throw them BEFORE trying to acquire lock. But this is an implementation detail and you can't be sure about it.

You can probably check how this method is implemented at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/ but, as I said, this is an implementation detail.